# Calculate values for all lat/long in another table based on where calculation

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'm working with data in Postgresql+PostGIS and I've stumped myself (probably from overthinking it). For each lat/long in a `site` table, I want to calculate an average of a field for all points within a certain distance of that lat/long. For example:

```
SELECT
       site.id,
       ring1.avg as r1_avg,
       ring5.avg as r5_avg
FROM
       (SELECT id, lon, lat FROM sites) as site,
       (SELECT avg(sales) FROM revenue WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326), (1.0*1609.34))) as ring1,
       (SELECT avg(sales) FROM revenue WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326), (5.0*1609.34))) as ring5;
```

Yep, the implicit/explicit syntax is bad form and wrong. That's what I'm struggling with: how to get the subqueries to pickup the lat/long from the `site` table and use it for the `WHERE` calculation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a recent version of PostgreSQL, you can use [LATERAL Joins](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html) to fix the dependency problem in your JOIN.

Without LATERAL, each sub-query in your FROM clause is evaluated independently and *cannot cross-reference any other items* in the FROM clause. The LATERAL keyword can precede a sub-query to allow reference to columns of FROM items that appear before (to the left of) it.

In your case, you can add the `LATERAL` keyword before the last two subqueries.

```
SELECT
       site.id,
       ring1.avg as r1_avg,
       ring5.avg as r5_avg
FROM
       (SELECT id, lon, lat FROM sites) as site,
       LATERAL (SELECT avg(sales) FROM revenue WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326), (1.0*1609.34))) as ring1,
       LATERAL (SELECT avg(sales) FROM revenue WHERE ST_DWithin(geom::geography, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326), (5.0*1609.34))) as ring5;
```

Comment: Nice, did not know about `LATERAL JOIN`. You can also move the `ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326)` to the `site` CTE so it's only done once (I assume that isn't being optimised): `(SELECT id, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography, 4326) AS geog FROM sites) as site`.

Comment: @RichardLaw You are right. That saves computation indeed.

Comment: This is exactly the solution I needed. Moving the St_MakePoint call also decreased runtime by a few minutes. Thanks tinylx and @RichardLaw for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Joining two times the same tables might be a bit slow.

You could just join once and make use of the [Filter function for aggregations](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) (older Versions use CASE WHEN inside the Aggregate function).

PostgreSQL > 9.4:

```
SELECT
   site.id,
   avg(revenue.sales) FILTER (WHERE ST_DWithin(revenue.geog, site.geog, (1.0*1609.34))) as r1_avg,
   avg(revenue.sales) as r5_avg
FROM
   ( select id, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(site.lon, site.lat)::geography as geog from site) as site
JOIN
   ( select sales, geom::geography as geog from revenue) as revenue
ON ST_DWithin(revenue.geog, site.geog, (5.0*1609.34));
```

PostgreSQL < 9.4:

exchange the line for `r1_avg` with the following:

```
avg(case when ST_DWithin(revenue.geog, site.geog, (1.0*1609.34)) then revenue.sales end) as r1_avg,
```

For performance improvement consider to create an index on `revenue.geom::geography`